# How to retry image loading, if Glide fails?

Tags: android, android-glide, loadimage

I am using this code to load the image from network.

I am making multiple request at the same time due to which the error comes `FileNotFound` but the file actually exist on server.

Therefore i want to ask that how can i retry the glide request if glide fails?

```
 public static void LoadNetworkImage(final Context context, final ImageView imageView, final String imageUrl) {

        Glide.with(context).
                load(imageUrl).
                listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                      //if loading fails then again make request

                        LoadNetworkImage(context,imageView,imageUrl);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }).
                into(imageView);
    }
```

i have studied this discussion [How to retry image loading ,if Glide fails?](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1307) but it did not help.

**Error Logs**

> class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load
>   resource
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpfhpbjdsf.png)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>         Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor, LOCAL,
>   DataCacheKey{sourceKey=http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpfhpbjdsf.png,
>   signature=EmptySignature}
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpfhpbjdsf.png)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>           Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpfhpbjdsf.png 07-30
>   20:51:35.127 18903-18903/com.example.muhammadusman.project I/Glide:
>   Root cause (1 of 1)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpfhpbjdsf.png
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1396)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1247)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1170)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:299)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
>   07-30 20:51:35.127 18903-18903/com.example.muhammadusman.project
>   D/MyMessage: Again loading 07-30 20:51:37.842 1397-1397/?
>   W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected
>   position 58480553 , only wrote 58327920 07-30 20:51:38.041
>   18903-18903/com.example.muhammadusman.project W/Glide: Load failed for
>   http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpqklezoyk.png with size [368x268]
>       class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpqklezoyk.png)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>         Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor, LOCAL,
>   DataCacheKey{sourceKey=http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpqklezoyk.png,
>   signature=EmptySignature}
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpqklezoyk.png)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>           Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpqklezoyk.png 07-30
>   20:51:38.041 18903-18903/com.example.muhammadusman.project I/Glide:
>   Root cause (1 of 1)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.0.2.2:5000/image/tmpqklezoyk.png
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1396)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1247)
>           at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1170)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:22)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.loadResource(AssetFileDescriptorLocalUriFetcher.java:13)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:44)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:299)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463084/how-to-specify-the-number-of-retries-using-glide-for-android-for-loading-images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250802/glide-call-method-after-fallback-or-error-when-trying-load-photo

Comment: show your log and server side code?

Answer (score 4):

This is the library [Weak Handler](https://github.com/badoo/android-weak-handler)

1.Add this library into the build.gradle file.

2.Code is given below.

**Code**

```
 public static void LoadNetworkImage(final Context context, final ImageView imageView, final String imageUrl) {



        final WeakHandler mHandler = new WeakHandler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LoadNetworkImage(context, imageView,imageUrl);
            }
        };

        Glide.with(context).
                load(imageUrl).
                transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).
                listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {


                        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1);
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }).
                into(imageView);
    }
```

**Note**
if your image loading fails then this code will sent the request after 1 MiiliSecond of failure. This will work best in your case only because you have said that the resource exist.

**Warning**
But if the resource does not exist then this is not the best solution. Because the recursion will go infinitely.